# dse-libcassandra-3.1.4-1.noarch conflicts with filesystem-3.2-13.fc19.x86_64

Tags: datastax-enterprise

I'm unable to install dse-full or opscenter due to the following transaction errors

```
Total    
Running transaction check
Running transaction test

Transaction check error:
  file /usr/bin from install of dse-libcassandra-3.1.4-1.noarch conflicts with file from package filesystem-3.2-13.fc19.x86_64
  file /usr/sbin from install of dse-libcassandra-3.1.4-1.noarch conflicts with file from package filesystem-3.2-13.fc19.x86_64

Error Summary
-------------
```

Is there some yum foo to get around this? Why would the package include a /user/bin and /usr/sbin?

****UPDATE Resolved****

I was able to work around this by doing the following:

Downloaded the latest rpm from the datastax repository using my login credentials:

```
wget http://xxx:xxx@rpm.datastax.com/enterprise/noarch/dse-libcassandra-3.1.4-1.noarch.rpm
```

Then ran:

```
rpm -Uvh --force dse-libcassandra-3.1.4-1.noarch.rpm
```

I had to do the same thing to get opscenter installed. I believe the rpm's were packaged incorrectly and hope it is resolved in a future release.

****NOTE****

If you use this solution you should also download the filesystem rpm and run:

```
rpm -Uvh --force filesystem-3.2-13.fc19.x86_64.rpm
```

This way /usr/bin and /usr/sbin is owned by the filesystem package again. Otherwise you might run into problems later trying to upgrade fedora.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is an issue in the rpm spec that has been resolved for upcoming releases. Both packages erroneously try to take control over /usr/bin and /usr/sbin.

Comment: Facing same conflict issue while upgrading from 1.2 to 2.0. Followed this link: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/upgrade/doc/upgrade/cassandra/upgradeRhelC_t.html